# Add buttons to reveal/hide information

Tags: objective-c, button, view

Views in my application have to show a lot of information. So I thought of special buttons or textfields that open when they get clicked. For example: like the buttons on Wikipedia mobile to expand categories to show more information or to hide unneeded information.

Does anybody know any good ways to implement this in my application?

---

I have an `UITableVIew`. Now I made my own TableViewCell. But if my Table appears nothing is shown - but the cells are still selectable and open the Detailview. Which command have I forgotten?

```
//Customize the appearance of table view cells.

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainTableCell";

MainTableCell *cell = (MainTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[MainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Configure the cell.
VerwaltungInformation *selectedFormel = [listOfFormularies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.FormelNameLabel.text = selectedFormel.nameFormel;

return cell;
}
```

Do I have to add special things? If somebody needs more code - please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to look for this is to look for disclosure buttons.

The way those are implemented in iOS, is using `UITableView`s with a grouped style. What you will probably be looking for is having a few sections, each section with one title cell (being this cell the only one at the section, at the index 0). So the pipeline for the user would be to touch the title cell and more info would appear on more cells or in one more cell.

If you can't imagine this think of how the available Wi-Fi networks appear.

You would be implementing the following methods from the [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class:

```
beginUpdates
endUpdates
insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:
```

Edit:

You will have to start by having a class for this disclosure behavior but first you will need to define a model that can probably be like this:

`DisclosureData`:

- Section Title (`NSString`)
- Extra Information (`NSString`)
- Section Open (`BOOL`)

After having that class defined you can probably now integrate it to your `UITableView` subclass, which will probably be called something like `DisclosureViewController`. And that object will probably have a `NSArray` property containing a bunch of `DisclosureData` objects.

Now all that's left to do is to implement your delegate table view the key methods to look at are:

```
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

In this section you will have to provide an XOR like behavior over the `DisclosureData` section open property; meaning that if the cell of that object is touched, you will have to open it if it is closed or close it if it is already opened.

And this method from the `UITableView` class:

```
cellForrRowAtIndexPath:
```

In this method, you will have to do the logic to know whether the section has one or two rows (one when closed, two probably when closed), also depending on how much text, you have to implement the `heighForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Also be sure to implement the following methods:
    `numberOfRowsInSection`

When performing the disclosure actions you will have to use edition blocks

```
beginUpdates
endUpdates
```

Comment: I can imagine what you are telling me - it is what i am looking for. But i do not really know how to integrate it into my app. Do you know under which *points* i can find this in a documentation or where i can find more about this what you said in general (like a short tutorial....)?

Comment: Hello Daniel, I have expanded my answer a little more, hopefully that will help you. If you have never worked with a `UITableView` you should look first to find a tutorial that you like and understand. That will help a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much !! I understand your explanatian and will work on it...thanks!

Comment: If  you happen to have any related problem, be sure to post here. I know that `UITableView`s are really tricky.

Comment: But there is one question I have...do you know where (under which cue)I can find maybe something more about this in the iOs Developer Library or somewhere else? Till now I could find something about Table View Cells but I cannot find a function like the wikipedia cells have...

Comment: Are you sure that this functions i want to have can be realized with a UITableView ? - I can make a TableView with elements which can be klicked but i do not know how to reach the function I desrcribed before...

Comment: Yes, with a `UITableView`, `UITableViewDelegate` and the `UITableViewController` (as a wrapper). Do you already have a working table view? With let's say, just the titles? If so, now you have to check the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, in there you will have to decide whether or not you want to show more information. In either of those cases, you will have to use the edition blocks (`beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`) to add or remove a cell. If you are adding a cell be sure to calculate the height of the content using the `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` method.

Comment: Full documentation for that last method can be found here on the NSString UIKit Additions Reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thank you for you help again. Everything works fine...Thank you!

Comment: Now  i have a little new problem...but I do not think that this is very big...i will make a new post for it.